# Quotes after a chapter begins

Tags: quotation

In the following code, I would like to modify the output so that it doesn't show an underline between the quote and the author of the quote.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{epigraph}

...

\chapter{Something}

\epigraph{All human things are subject to decay, and when fate 
summons, Monarchs must obey}{\textit{Mac Flecknoe \\ John Dryden}}
```

I chose the epigraph package because it's the only one that allows me to place a quote after a chapter begins.If there are other suggestions, I'm looking forward to. Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Something}

\epigraph{All human things are subject to decay, and when fate
summons, Monarchs must obey}{\textit{Mac Flecknoe \\ John Dryden}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, how do I set a right margin to my epigraph?

Comment: @Avocado What do you mean by right margin? Perhaps you should ask another question about that with a diagram showing what you are after.

Comment: @PeterWilson as in having the quote and it's author moved from the left towards the center by a couple inches.